# Spring Boot Resilience4J Annotation Not Opening Circuit

Tags: java, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I've checked the questions on the site about Resilience4J, but have not had any luck with their answers. I'm trying to implement `@CircuitBreaker` annotation from Resilience4J in my Spring Boot 2.x project. The circuit breaker is implemented around a pretty straightforward function. However, when I supply a bad URL, the circuit is not opening, no matter how many times I send the request. I've gone so far as to extract everything into a standalone application and run it 100 times and observe it just endlessly failing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```java
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "backendA")
    @Component
    public class ResilientClient {

        private HttpClient httpClient;

        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResilientClient.class);

        public ResilientClient() {

            httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
        }


        @Bulkhead(name = "backendA")
        public String processPostRequest(String body, String[] headers, String url) {

            HttpResponse<String> response = null;

            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
                .headers(headers)
                .build();

            try {
                response =  httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "This is a remote exception");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error("Interrupted Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

            }
            return response != null ? response.body() : null;
    };

// None of these functions ever get invoked

    private String fallback(Throwable e){
        log.info("generic throwable caught");
        return "generic result";
    }

    private String fallback(String param1, String[] headers, String url, Throwable e) {
        log.info("Fallback method invoked for Throwable: " + param1);
        return null;
    }

    private String fallback(String param1, String[] headers, String url, ConnectException e) {
        log.info("Fallback method invoked for ConnectException: " + param1);
        return null;
    }

}
```

The config file is taken directly from the Github example

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: false
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 2s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      recordExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.io.IOException
      ignoreExceptions:
        - io.github.robwin.exception.BusinessException
    shared:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 100
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 30
      waitDurationInOpenState: 1s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      ignoreExceptions:
        - io.github.robwin.exception.BusinessException
  instances:
    backendA:
      baseConfig: default
    backendB:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 10
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      waitDurationInOpenState: 1s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      recordFailurePredicate: io.github.robwin.exception.RecordFailurePredicate
resilience4j.retry:
  configs:
    default:
      maxRetryAttempts: 2
      waitDuration: 100
      retryExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.io.IOException
      ignoreExceptions:
        - io.github.robwin.exception.BusinessException
  instances:
    backendA:
      maxRetryAttempts: 3
    backendB:
      maxRetryAttempts: 3
resilience4j.bulkhead:
  configs:
    default:
      maxConcurrentCalls: 100
  instances:
    backendA:
      maxConcurrentCalls: 10
    backendB:
      maxWaitDuration: 10ms
      maxConcurrentCalls: 20

resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead:
  configs:
    default:
      maxThreadPoolSize: 4
      coreThreadPoolSize: 2
      queueCapacity: 2
  instances:
    backendA:
      baseConfig: default
    backendB:
      maxThreadPoolSize: 1
      coreThreadPoolSize: 1
      queueCapacity: 1

resilience4j.ratelimiter:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: false
      limitForPeriod: 10
      limitRefreshPeriod: 1s
      timeoutDuration: 0
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 100
  instances:
    backendA:
      baseConfig: default
    backendB:
      limitForPeriod: 6
      limitRefreshPeriod: 500ms
      timeoutDuration: 3s
```

Code to try testing it

```java
SpringBootApplication
public class CircuitsApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CircuitsApplication.class);

    static ResilientClient resilientClient = new ResilientClient();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(CircuitsApplication.class, args);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            try {
                String body = "body content";
                String[] headers = new String[]{"header", "value"};
                String url = "http://a.bad.url";
                String result = resilientClient.processPostRequest(body, headers, url);
                logger.info(result);
            } catch (Exception ex){
                logger.info("Error caught in main loop");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried adding the Circuitbreaker annotation to the method itself. I've tried creating a supplier and decorating it. I've tried adding the Bulkhead, removing the Bulkhead. I've tried adding additional fallback methods with different signatures. I've tried with and without `@Component`.

All I end up getting in my logs is this 100 times:

```
14:33:10.348 [main] INFO c.t.circuits.CircuitsApplication - Error caught in main loop
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to resole this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will work. Firstly, you are instantiating your `ResilientClient` as `new ResilientClient()`. You have to use the created Bean not instantiate it yourselves. The `@CircuitBreaker` annotation uses spring-aop. So you will have to run your class as SpringBootApplicaiton.

Secondly, you are only recording `HttpServerErrorException` and `IOException` as failures. So circuit breaker treats all other exceptions (except the ones mentioned above and their children) as success.

Comment: To be clear, the above code was me pulling the code out of my Spring Boot application. :) Right now, the client is instantiated from the service layer in the constructor using ```(@Autowired ResilientClient resilientClient)```  There are several items for using Resilience4J in Spring Boot 2 that are not covered in the documentation, including needing to have Spring autowire the bean or setting up a config class and the example Java code in the docs has an undefined variable

Comment: Try adding `java.lang.Throwable` to `resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default. recordExceptions` if you want to retry on all exceptions. You can add ignored exceptions to `resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default. ignoreExceptions`

Comment: By default all exceptions count as a failure. You don't have to add Throwable to recordExceptions. You just have to add exceptions to the list of ignoreExpections.

Comment: Yes if you don't configure the `recordExceptions` they do. But if you put a list of exceptions in `recordExceptions` config they don't.

`recordExceptions`: A list of exceptions that are recorded as a failure and thus increase the failure rate.
Any exception matching or inheriting from one of the list counts as a failure, unless explicitly ignored via ignoreExceptions.
If you specify a list of exceptions, all other exceptions count as a success, unless they are explicitly ignored by ignoreExceptions.

Comment: I know it. I wrote it. :) If you don't specify a list of exceptions which should be recorded. All exceptions are recorded unless they are explicity ignored.

Comment: @Jeremy Smith Which items are missing in the documentation? You can create a GitHub issue if something is missing for you.

Comment: @RobertWinkler, specifically I'm talking about the documentation here: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3 so I'm not sure how you'd want that opened in GitHub. :) In your annotation section, the variable BACKEND is not defined within the example code. There is no mention that the class being annotated has to be declared as a component or have the bean defined in a configuration file - it mentions only that it should be configured in application.yml.  While the sample code in GitHub has this, the documentation does not.

Comment: @RobertWinkler there were some other steps I had to take to get things working in addition, but I'd have to go back through. Additionally, to get the sample project working, I had to change the gradle wrapper and the build.gradle, as I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, not Eclipse, although I didn't really consider that to be a major issue, as that's really dependent on the particular individual. Having a POM-based example might also be helpful.

Comment: @AkhilBojedla please help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407909/using-circuit-breaker-in-spring-boot